# Text Area spacing when inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql

so i have this Text area wherein the data will be posted to the database.

[image]

so here is an image of what my sample input might look like.it has spacing via enter key but when it is send to the database the spacing wont be there and the display of the input will be

[image]

```
<?php
    require("common.php");
    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }
?>
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password=""; 
$db_name="phplogin"; 
$tbl_name="tasks"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$Ttoday=$_POST['comment1'];
$task_issues=$_POST['comment2'];
$Ttom=$_POST['comment3'];
$id=$_POST['comment'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(task_today, issues, task_tom, U_ID)VALUES('$Ttoday', '$task_issues', '$Ttom', '$id')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
header("Location: private.php");
exit;
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

here is my insert codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nl2br()`. Try this,

`$Ttoday= nl2br($_POST['comment1'])`;

Comment: it didnt read the command <br/> but it wrote as a string instead

Comment: @Yinks In table, it cannot insert in next line etc.. You have to convert those to HTML entites. Then while displaying you can show it as it is created.

Comment: use htmlentites() &  htmlspecialchars(). Go through these. Both doing some distinct functions. You can use according to your requirement

Comment: @EdwinAlex He can store `NL` or `LF` in the database. The problem is that when he is outputing the data as html, these `NL` or `LF` won't be visible until he doesn't insert the content into `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: @Ander2 In that case, he has to output within the tags everytime. Better he can convert it to <br />. He doesn't need any extra tags know. He can show this format of texts in both HTML page and PHP page

Comment: ok thank i did it. i was using htmlentities which is i think the reason it didnt read the command <br/>.i just remove it and it worked thanks thanks!